# How to use flash[] to store an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I mostly understand what `flash[]` does, so I don't think that's the issue, but I think I have a syntax error somewhere? Documentation and Google are not helping, and I can't find a similar question on SO. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to assign data to flash[] like so:

```
flash[:successful_submission] = {email: owner.email}
```

But when I try to retrieve it, it's not there:

```
flash[:successful_submission][:email]
```

but when I inspect instead:

```
flash[:successful_submission].inspect
```

I get:

```
{"email"=>"email@address.com"}
```

What's going on here??

Comment: When did you check flash[:successful_submission], in the same action or the next action?

Comment: It's the next action from the one in which it's assigned. I'm pretty sure the issue is the format/syntax I'm using to assign or retrieve the data, and doesn't have to do with flash[]

Comment: It looks like your hash is stringified, have you tried `flash[:successful_submission]['email']` (instead of `[:email]`)?

Comment: @anothermh THANK YOU! That was it. It's a small, subtle difference, and really hard to Google for.

Comment: [Parameter values are always strings; Rails makes no attempt to guess or cast the type](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters)...and there is no difference in the way Rails handles query string params and POST(etc) params

Comment: @MarkMerritt Not relevant here as that refers to values, not keys. Additionally, `params` always permits indifferent access, and is a different object type from `flash`.

Comment: @anothermh I was under the assumption that the same concept applies to the flash (cookies). May be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

from @anothermh's comment:

```
flash[:successful_submission]['email']
```

This works, I think because it's a hash, not an object

Comment: A hash can have anything for keys. When you use a string it can either be stringified (`"email"`) or symbolized (`:email`). The example you showed of `{email: owner.email}` is symbolized so I'm not sure why it's being stringified after being put into the flash, but you can tell it is because when you inspect it it looks like `{"email"=>"email@address.com"}`. It might be a Rails thing. You may be able to do `{email: owner.email}.with_indifferent_access` to allow you to use either string or symbol access.

Comment: @anothermh A Hash can have anything, but when you serialize it so you can store it in a cookie a lot of things get converted from Symbol to String.

Comment: Makes sense to me!